# Dynamic Mobx Stores in React Native

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

This is kinda a vague question

I have a React Native component that is going to be used in a ListView, each one is going to be slightly different in the sense that each component is populated different information in its props, each component also needs a mobx store to help pass information. Is there a way to dynamically create Mobx stores so each component has a Mobx store?

I was almost thinking like have a base mobx store class that each component uses, but not sure if this is the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

When I understand your question right, you have the same data, but every list shows this data in a different way?

For that case you would create a computed prop for every list.
Fetch the data once, store it in a observable prop but let your lists use the computed props. In the computed props transform or do whatever you want with the fetched data.

https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html#-computed